WireGuard Handshake Fails When Routing Peer Traffic Through tun2socks
I am building a setup where my laptop connects to VPS1 using WireGuard (WG). Then, all traffic from VPS1 should be routed to VPS2 via a Shadowsocks tunnel using tun2socks. The objective is to have all traffic from the laptop routed through the Shadowsocks tunnel, effectively having internet access through VPS2 after connecting to VPS1 via WireGuard.
My Current Setup:

Laptop runs a WireGuard client (10.0.0.2).
VPS1 has three interfaces:

eth0: Public IP of VPS1 ($VPS1_IP).
wg0: WireGuard interface (10.0.0.1).
tun0: TUN interface used by tun2socks (10.0.1.1/24), routing traffic through the Shadowsocks client to VPS2.


VPS2 runs the Shadowsocks server, and all internet traffic is routed through it.

My Goal:

Establish a WireGuard tunnel from my laptop to VPS1.
Route all peer traffic (internet-bound traffic) from the laptop through tun0 (using tun2socks) and then through the Shadowsocks tunnel to VPS2 for internet access.

Diagram:
(Not sure if I drew it correctly)

The Issue:
When I first connect to VPS1 using WireGuard from the laptop and then run the script to bring up tun0 and set the routing table for peer traffic, everything works fine. The traffic is correctly routed to VPS2 and the internet.
However, if I run the script before attempting to establish the WireGuard connection, the handshake between the laptop and VPS1 fails. After some debugging, I found that the issue arises when this routing rule is added:
ip route add default dev tun0 table wg_tun

If I remove this route, the handshake works again, but the traffic is no longer routed through tun0 and the Shadowsocks tunnel.
Script for Starting tun0 on VPS1:
#!/bin/bash
# Bring up the tun0 interface
/root/go/bin/tun2socks -device tun0 -proxy socks5://127.0.0.1:1086 &
tun2socks_pid=$!

# Wait for tun2socks to start
while ! ip link show tun0 > /dev/null 2>&1; do
  sleep 1
done

# Set up the tun interface
ip addr add 10.0.1.1/24 dev tun0
ip link set dev tun0 up

# Set up routing tables
ip rule add from 10.0.0.0/24 table wg_tun
ip route add default dev tun0 table wg_tun

# Apply firewall rules
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -s 10.0.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -o tun0 -s 10.0.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o wg0 -d 10.0.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT

wait $tun2socks_pid

Question:
I assume, that the added rule somehow re-routes WG handshake request and thus WG cannot connect. If so, how can I modify my routing or firewall setup so that the WireGuard handshake is not disrupted, while still ensuring that all peer traffic (internet-bound) is routed through tun0 and then through the Shadowsocks tunnel to VPS2?
What is the correct way to allow the WireGuard handshake to pass through while still routing peer traffic through the tun2socks interface?

The WireGuard handshake will not involve the wg0 or tun0 interfaces at all, just the eth0 interface. Try running ip rule on VPS1 to make sure that you have no other policy routing rules involving the wg_tun table that would be re-routing traffic sent to or from the WireGuard listen port on the eth0 interface.

ip rule has only the following rules: 0: from all lookup local | 32765: from 10.0.0.0/24 lookup wg_tun | 32766: from all lookup main | 32767: from all lookup default. From what I see, there is only that one rule, that forwards WG tunnel traffic to tun0.
